# Reassigning String Value in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I'm a first year C student and I'm working on a project where we must create a times table in a given base that the user inputs. I've almost completely finished it but I'm having trouble removing leading zeros from the table.

This is what the simple base 10 table looks like.

```
andrew@andrew-VirtualBox ~/cs211/project1 $ ./timesTable 10

   |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |     
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
 0 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  00 |  
 1 |  00 |  01 |  02 |  03 |  04 |  05 |  06 |  07 |  08 |  09 |  
 2 |  00 |  02 |  04 |  06 |  08 |  10 |  12 |  14 |  16 |  18 |  
 3 |  00 |  03 |  06 |  09 |  12 |  15 |  18 |  21 |  24 |  27 |  
 4 |  00 |  04 |  08 |  12 |  16 |  20 |  24 |  28 |  32 |  36 |  
 5 |  00 |  05 |  10 |  15 |  20 |  25 |  30 |  35 |  40 |  45 |  
 6 |  00 |  06 |  12 |  18 |  24 |  30 |  36 |  42 |  48 |  54 |  
 7 |  00 |  07 |  14 |  21 |  28 |  35 |  42 |  49 |  56 |  63 |  
 8 |  00 |  08 |  16 |  24 |  32 |  40 |  48 |  56 |  64 |  72 |  
 9 |  00 |  09 |  18 |  27 |  36 |  45 |  54 |  63 |  72 |  81 |  
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

I want to remove the leading zeros from each number but I'm struggling to get it working. Here's what the function code looks like.

```
char * toHex(int n, int q){

    static char hexNumber[4] = {0x00};
    char digits[16]={ '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    unsigned int un = q;


    int i;

    for(i=1; i>=0; i--){
        hexNumber[i] = digits[un%n];
        un=un/n;        
    }
    if(strcmp(hexNumber, "0") == 0){
        hexNumber = " ";
    }   
    return hexNumber; 
}
```

Using my logic, I'm trying to reassign the hexNumber string to an empty " " string so the zeros just don't appear, but I get the error:

```
timesTable.c: In function ‘toHex’:
timesTable.c:68:13: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[4]’ from type ‘char *’
   hexNumber = " ";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the messed up formatting it the post. I'm new around here and haven't gotten the hang of formatting

Comment: Using "memcpy(hexNumber, " ", 2)" fixed the error but doesn't remove any zeros.

Comment: When you say remove leading zeros, do you mean that "01" should be " 1" instead? Your code will just set hexNumber to a space if it's "0", which I don't think will ever happen.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reassign `char[]` types, and you can't modify a `const char[]`. So you must do:

- `char hexNumber[4] = {0x00};`

And when you want to assign:

- `memcpy(hexNumber, " ", 2)` (if you have strings.h imported)
- `hexNumber[0] = ' '; hexNumber[1] = '\0';` (if you don't want to import anything)

Edit: The above fixes the error. For correctness of your program, maybe this is what you want to replace your `if(strcmp...` code with?

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (hexNumber[i] == '0') {
        hexNumber[i] = ' ';
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will check from the start of the string for 0 characters, replacing them with space characters until it reaches a non-0 character.

You also can't return `hexNumber` if you define it as an array on your stack, so instead do `char* hexNumber = malloc(4);` then `memset(hexNumber, '\0', 4)` (make sure you `import <strings.h>` at the top). This allocates it on the *heap* instead of the stack. Whatever calls this function will need to eventually `free` the result or else you'll have a memory leak. Alternatively, you could make this function accept `hexNumber` as an input and make the caller allocate it however it wants, which is what many C library functions dealing with strings do.

Comment: So now I get: andrew@andrew-VirtualBox ~/cs211/project1 $ gcc -g -Wall -o timesTable timesTable.c
timesTable.c: In function ‘toHex’:
timesTable.c:72:1: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 return hexNumber; 
 ^
And it doesn't remove zeros.

Comment: Right... You shouldn't return `hexNumber` since it's on the stack for this function. I was just thinking of fixing syntax errors. Editing the answer. You'll need to malloc it instead of creating on the stack. And remember to free it after.

Comment: The code you suggested to replace strcmp worked. I actually tried a solution very similar to that earlier but didn't get it to work. That caused me to look for more complex routes. Thanks for the help, I'm glad it was much simpler than I thought.